# Ссылка выходит за рамки div

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, есть блок с шириной в 20%, он обернут в ссылку, все хорошо, да вот только ссылка почему-то по ширине занимает 100% документа, пробовал и задавать ширину, и прочее - не выходит, не могу понять, в чем причина, прочитал как оборачивать блок в ссылку но так, как описано - не выходит, может кто подскажет.
Вот код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>border-spacing</title>
  <style>

       .div1 {
           display:block;
           width:20%;
           height:80px;
           background:red;
       }
  
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <a href="#ler"><div class="div1"></div></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
.div1 {
    /*display:block*/
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#ler">
    <div class="div1"></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

По хорошему, блочный элемент нельзя помещать в строчный. Поэтому такая ерунда и происходит.

Лучше сделать так (если есть такая возможность):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>border-spacing</title>
  <style>
       .div1 {
           display:block;
           width:20%;
           height:80px;
           background:red;
       }
       .link {
           display: inline-block; 
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%
       }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div class="div1"><a href="#ler" class="link"></a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Советую почитать вам о [блочной модели документа](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) и о том, как правильно с ней работать :)

Answer (score 1):

Например так можно решить (поменять местами ширину немножко):

```css
a {
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
}

.div1 {
    display:block;
    height:80px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#ler"><div class="div1"></div></a>
```

Comment: в .div1 width: 100%; - он по умолчанию равен 100%

Answer (score 0):

Добавил в css `position: absolute`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>border-spacing</title>
  <style>
       .div1 {
           display:block;
           width:20%;
           height:80px;
           background:red;
           position: absolute;
       }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <a href="#ler"><div class="div1"></div></a>
 </body>
</html>
```